# Eventos javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, html-tabla, html-select

Buenas,

Esto es una fila de mi tabla, cada una de ellas tiene un evento onclick. Al pulsar en el select llama a ese evento cosa que no debería hacer. Como puedo hacer para que si se pulsa en el select, abra el select y si se pulsa fuera del select actue el evento

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál evento no debe llamar? El del select o el del onclick?

Comment: Podrias facilitar el codigo donde estan definidos los eventos?

Comment: **Es importante que leas [ask]**, debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes, y si es posible crear un snippet para ejecutarlo, slaudos.

Comment: Debes colocar tus dudas mas el codigo para ver como estas empleando el codigo y lograr intempretar tu objetivo

Comment: No he puesto el codigo porque se genera dinamicamente y no beneficiaria en la pregunta (en mi opinion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El evento click se genera en el elemento sobre el que se hace click con el ratón y se propaga hacia arriba generándose en todos los elementos superiores en el árbol del DOM.

Para evitarlo captura el evento en el elemento `select` y utiliza el método `stopPropagation` para detener la propagación del evento:

```js
$(function(){
  $('tr').click(() => console.log('click fila'));
  
  $('#mySelect').click((e) => e.stopPropagation());
});
```

```css
table tr td{
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #666666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="fila">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
        <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
        <option value="4">Opción 4</option>
        <option value="5">Opción 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es algo que no conocía, esto me lo ha solucionado